# Not able to retrieve RadTextBox/ASP.NET TextBox updated value in RadAjaxPanel

Tags: asp.net, telerik

This is really awkward. I am working on Telerik controls.  I have a .NET web usercontrol which have some RadCombo boxes and a newly added RadTextBox.  All of this  in a RadAjaxPanel and RadLoadingAjaxPanel.  When the user control loads, all of the control load values from database, including RadTextBox.

(The problem starts here) And when I try to update the RadTextBox control value and try to submit, I "Always" get the old value of the textbox.

Comment: "newly added RadTextBox" - does this mean that you are dynamically adding it to the form?  Can you include some markup?

Comment: @BrianMains - Nope, the new RadTextBox has been added into the markup. 

<telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1"  BackgroundPosition="Center" Transparency="1" Skin="Vista" runat="server">
</telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
<telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="rpanel" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server">
                           <telerik:RadTextBox Skin="Vista" ID="txt_varTemplateContent" Columns="60" 
                            runat="server" />

I am not able to paste more markup :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your `Page_Load` event and verify that you have an `if(!IsPostBack)` surrounding the code that loads the original values to the `RadTextBox`.

Comment: Thanks a ton man... u saved my another day :)

It's really stupid of me to put that code outside of !IsPostback, but believe me, it was unintentional. :P

But still Thanks alot again.

Cheers